# Django ORM query: how to swap value of a attribute?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

Here is the case. I want to swap value of user.

```
user_with_apple = User.objects.filter(fruit=apple)
user_with_pear = User.objects.filter(fruit=pear)

user_with_apple.update(fruit=pear)
user_with_pear.update(fruit=apple)
```

Well, this does not work, as everything ends up with pear. Because django ORM is lazy, I suppose?

So may I ask how can I perform such a "swap" operation? Do I have to use a intermediate value?

Thank you so much!

Or does it make sense if I force the evaluation of the query by slicing or calling list() on it? 
eg.
    user_with_apple = User.objects.filter(fruit=apple)[:]
    user_with_pear = User.objects.filter(fruit=pear)[:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what that comes to mind:

If you call `list` on your QuerySets, you force Django to give you the objects. The problem with this is that you can't call `update` on a list, so you need to iterate over the lists, and update each object.

This may help you on your way:

```
users_with_apple = list(User.objects.filter(fruit=apple))
users_with_pear = list(User.objects.filter(fruit=pear))

for user in users_with_apple:
    user.fruit = pear
    user.save()
for user in users_with_pear:
    user.fruit = apple
    user.save()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer man! I think it will work. But in that case, I all have to call .save() on each of them separately right? Does that means I have to hit the db a lot of time ? @Steinar

Comment: That's probably correct. I don't __think__ this will produce extra db calls.

Comment: @noooooooob yes, every time you call `save()` db do `update`.

Comment: @DoNotArrestMe Is that different from using `update`?

Comment: @DoNotArrestMe I don't think I can use update() after slicing or calling list() :(

Comment: @SteinarLima if I use `update` like in my answer - I have only 3 `update` query to db behind django orm. If I change value in loop and call `save()` - then I have `update` query to db every time.

Comment: @noooooooob yes you can not use `update` after slicing or calling `list()`

Comment: @noooooooob after slicing or calling `list()` you can only use `save()`. If you want to use `update()` then use like `User.objects.filter().update()`

Answer (score 1):

### Variant 1

I suppose you have `CharField` for `fruit`. Then add `unknown` option to choice.

```
FRUIT_CHOICES = (
    ...
    (unknown, 'Unknown'),
    (apple, 'Apple'),
    (pear, 'Pear'),
    ...
)

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    fruit = models.CharField(..., choices=FRUIT_CHOICES)
    ...
```

Then try this.

```
User.objects.filter(fruit=apple).update(fruit=unknown)
User.objects.filter(fruit=pear).update(fruit=apple)
User.objects.filter(fruit=unknown).update(fruit=pear)
```

### Variant 2

Add access null values for `fruit` field.

```
FRUIT_CHOICES = (
    ...
    (apple, 'Apple'),
    (pear, 'Pear'),
    ...
)

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    fruit = models.CharField(..., blank=True, null=True, choices=FRUIT_CHOICES)
    ...

User.objects.filter(fruit=apple).update(fruit=None)
User.objects.filter(fruit=pear).update(fruit=apple)
User.objects.filter(fruit=None).update(fruit=pear)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! @DoNotArrestMe! This feel like the classic "switch the value of 2 integer" solution and only hit the db 3 times. Hmm, will try it out.

Comment: @noooooooob you are welcome! Yes it is. If you need performance - this is only 3 `update` query to db behind django orm.

Comment: too bad fruit cannot be None in my case ?

Comment: @noooooooob Well, set it to something else than (which is not in your db), e.g. FooBar

Comment: @noooooooob what type fruit field have?

Comment: @noooooooob well then my answer not useful for you)

Comment: @DoNotArrestMe Thanks again man for the comprehensive example. I actually prefer your answer. But in my case it's not working. I will definitely come back to give it a upvote once I have more reps :)

Comment: @DoNotArrestMe: I saw you making a lot of edits to other posts. Please make only substancial edits. Your edits need to be approved by at least 3 others. Make your edits the time worth. And please don't add gimmick table style to example data. That does not really improve anything. Thank you.

Comment: @juergend Ok. I see. I do not more use gimmick table style to example data.